# Can can I call a function in the same Erlang Parameterised module?

Tags: erlang

I have a paramterised module in Erlang in which I wish to call a function A from within function B of the same parameterised module. How can I do this?

Comment: Great example of another reason to stay away from parameterized modules. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.79&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper:

> in every function of an abstract module, the variable THIS
>   is always implicitly bound to the current module instance

So you can simply write inside a function B:

```
THIS:A().
```

Comment: You don't have to do this when calling functions within the same module, the THIS is automatically handle. It is actually added to the arguments. Calling `THIS:b()` can only be used for exported functions and will then become a normal erlang "remote" call. The examples are very short but look in Fig 3.

Answer (score 2):

Just to recapitulate in an answer. You don't have to do anything special to call functions within a parametrised module, just write the code as you normally would. It is only when want to make an "remote" call to an exported function from within the module you need `THIS:a()`. Externally you need the parametrised module reference.

Though I agree with @Christian, stay away from them, you don't really need them.